# Application is visible on taskbar?

Tags: windows, delphi, taskbar

How to know if a Application is visible on taskbar?

I am using Delphi on windows.

Comment: I think you gave too less information. An VCL Delphi application always has a taskbar button, so the answer would be "You know because it is always there".

Comment: I removed the taskbar button of some applications

Comment: Please document what you mean by "removed the taskbar" button.  Provide the code or property to do this.

Comment: By "a(n) application" do you mean YOUR application, another application that's for sure running but may or may not be on the taskbar?  Do you mean how to tell if another person's application is running at all and the way you're used to referring to it is that's on the taskbar?  There's lots of ways to interpret this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try :

```
{Wnd = your app. handle}

    if IsWindowVisible(Wnd) 
       and
       ( (GetWindowLong(Wnd, GWL_HWNDPARENT) = 0) or (HWND(GetWindowLong(Wnd, GWL_HWNDPARENT)) = GetDesktopWindow) ) 
       and
       ((GetWindowLong(Wnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) and WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) = 0)
    then 
      // your application is visible on taskbar
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you play with

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;
```

and

```
Application.MainForm.Visible := False;
Application.ShowMainForm := False;
```